# How to write dynamic select expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to write some dynamic select expression on entity framework something like in the example.

```
var list = db.Article
    .GroupBy(x => x.CategoryId)
    .Select(x => new ArtDto
    {
        No = x.Select(c => c.NUMBER).FirstOrDefault(),
        UserName = x.Key,
        Count = x.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

I can write group by with expression like this:

```
Expression<Func<Article, int>> groupByExp;
groupByExp = (x) => x.CategoryId;
```

So I can replace actual expression with groupByExp.

```
var list = db.Article
    .GroupBy(groupByExp)
    .Select(x => new ArtDto
    {
        No = x.Select(c => c.NUMBER).FirstOrDefault(),
        UserName = x.Key,
        Count = x.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

I also want to write another expression for select. So I can send it to another function and it will be dynamic on that function.

```
Expression<Func<Article, bool>> selectExp;
selectExp = (x) => new ArtDto { ... };
```

Is it possible? Do you have any idea or tutorial for that?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to try?  Did you think about the consequences for `var list` ?

Comment: You can just pass different `Func<IGrouping<Article>, ArtDto>` into select

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek can you give me an example?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just updated my post. I need to write another expression for select and I can send that expression to another function. So it will be dynamic.

Comment: So, what type should `list` be?  This could only be made to work by returning `dynamic` everywhere.

Comment: Come up with a usage example. It doesn't have to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible,

before start you need to:

- Create the new object for selected properties
- Map your model to the new object

lets consider that you have your model `Article` and you need to return the new model `ArticleSummary` as below

```cs
public class Article {
 public int id { get; set; }
 public string Title { get; set; }
 public string Introduction { get; set; }
 public string AuthorId { get; set; }
 public AppUser Author { get; set; }
 public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleSummary {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Title { get; set; }
 public string Introduction { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the mapping :

```cs
Expression<Func<Article, ArticleSummary>> mapArticle = x => new ArticleSummary {
    Id = x.Id,
    Title = x.Title,
    Introduction = x.Introduction
};
```

and here is the "simplified" data function :

```cs
// T is Article model
// U is ArticleSummary model
public async Task<ICollection<U>> SelectListAsync<T, U>(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> search,
            Expression<Func<T, U>> select) where T : class
{
    var query =
    _context.Set<T>()
    .Where(search)
    .Select(select);

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

you can call it by passing mapping expression to select property.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression should take `IIGrouping<T, Article>` as first argument (where `T` is a type of `CategoryId`). Assuming that CategoryId is `int` expression can be written like

```
public static Expression<Func<IGrouping<int, Article>, ArtDto>> SelectExpression()
{
    return x => new ArtDto
    {
        No = x.Select(c => c.NUMBER).FirstOrDefault(),
        UserName = x.Key,
        Count = x.Count()
    };
}
```